# Multiple controllers for one view - request for the model not set

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I got the following code:

```
App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({});

App.Router.map(function(){
  this.resource('clients', { path : '/' });
});

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api'
});

App.ClientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  setupController: function(controller, model){
    controller.set('model', model);
    this.controllerFor('patients').set('model', this.store.find('patient'));
  }
});
```

When the main page is loaded a request is sent only to localhost:3000/api/patients and not to clients which is the main controller for the given view :/

Can you spot the mistake? I am using `App.ApplicationSerializer = DS.ActiveModelSerializer.extend({});`

I thought that might be the error, but after removing it I saw no changes at all.

Answer (score 1):

You are not defining the model for `ClientsRoute`:

```
App.ClientsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.find('client');
  }
});
```

The only case where its not necessary to define the model, is when the route is a simple dynamic segment (show a specific record). Example:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.route('client', { path: '/clients/:client_id' });
});

App.ClientRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  // Default model (no need to explicitly define it):
  // model: function(params) {
  //   return this.store.find('client', params.client_id);
  // }
});
```